# How to download files(e.g png, jpeg,pdf,msg) using Amazon S3 presigned url in java?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

I have generated presigned url using which preview is coming of that file but I want to download that file which I'm not able to do it. Is there any way by which we can get presigned download url using java.

Comment: A presigned url is really just a normal url to a file. Download the file just like you would download any other file.

Comment: Thanks @smac2020 for answering, in case of pdf file download button is coming on preview but if the file is png/jpeg then except that preview nothing is coming and also the requirement is there should be 1 preview button and 1 download button. Preview button is working but download is not working sine we don't have such presigned url.

Comment: I will test this Java V2 code with a PNG file

Comment: See the Updated part of my answer. PNG files work fine when using V2.

Answer (score 1):

Normally when you a sign a URL, by default S3 doesn't add any additional headers, which will cause most modern browsers to open a PDF file in the browser.  If you want the browser to download the file instead, you need to signal the download with a "[Content-Disposition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition)" header.

There's a fairly easy way to add the Content-Disposition to the S3 response by only changing how the presigned link is generated.  You just need to add a call to `responseContentDisposition` to the builder for the `GetObjectRequest`, for instance, this simple app will generate a link useful for "preview", and a link that will trigger a download for the same object:

```java
package com.example.myapp;

import java.time.Duration;
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.GetObjectRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.presigner.model.GetObjectPresignRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.presigner.model.PresignedGetObjectRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.presigner.S3Presigner;

public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        String bucketName = "example-bucket";
        String keyName = "test.pdf";
        Region region = Region.US_WEST_2;
        String downloadFilename = "the_filename_to_download_to.pdf";

        S3Presigner presigner = S3Presigner.builder().region(region).build();

        // Generate the presigned request, this will be the "preview" URL
        GetObjectRequest getObjectRequest = GetObjectRequest.builder()
                .bucket(bucketName).key(keyName).build();

        GetObjectPresignRequest getObjectPresignRequest = GetObjectPresignRequest.builder()
            .signatureDuration(Duration.ofHours(1))
            .getObjectRequest(getObjectRequest)
            .build();

        PresignedGetObjectRequest presignedGetObjectRequest = presigner
            .presignGetObject(getObjectPresignRequest);

        // Log the presigned URL
        System.out.println("Presigned URL for preview: " + presignedGetObjectRequest.url());

        // Generate the presigned request, this will be the "download" URL
        // Note, the addition of the content-encoding and content-disposition headers
        getObjectRequest = GetObjectRequest.builder()
                .bucket(bucketName).key(keyName)
                .responseContentEncoding("application/octet-stream")
                .responseContentDisposition("attachment; filename=\"" + downloadFilename + "\"")
                .build();

        getObjectPresignRequest = GetObjectPresignRequest.builder()
            .signatureDuration(Duration.ofHours(1))
            .getObjectRequest(getObjectRequest)
            .build();

        presignedGetObjectRequest = presigner
            .presignGetObject(getObjectPresignRequest);

        // Log the presigned URL
        System.out.println("Presigned URL for download: " + presignedGetObjectRequest.url());
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Anon, I used your approach but getting this error "Unable to load credentials from WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider(): Either the environment variable AWS_WEB_IDENTITY_TOKEN_FILE or the javaproperty aws.webIdentityTokenFile must be set." and I don't know ho to get this token and what I building is aws lambda.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to perform use cases with Amazon S3 and Java SDK, always look at the code [example repo in Github](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javav2/example_code/s3/src/main/java/com/example/s3). This is AWS SDK for Java V2 - which is much better practice to use then V1.

You will find many examples that have been tested such as this one that shows you how to get an object located in an Amazon S3 bucket by using the **S3Presigner** client object.

```
package com.example.s3;

// snippet-start:[presigned.java2.getobjectpresigned.import]
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.time.Duration;
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.GetObjectRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.S3Exception;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.presigner.model.GetObjectPresignRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.presigner.model.PresignedGetObjectRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.presigner.S3Presigner;
import software.amazon.awssdk.utils.IoUtils;
// snippet-end:[presigned.java2.getobjectpresigned.import]

/**
 * To run this AWS code example, ensure that you have setup your development environment, including your AWS credentials.
 *
 * For information, see this documentation topic:
 *
 * https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/get-started.html
 */

public class GetObjectPresignedUrl {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final String USAGE = "\n" +
                "Usage:\n" +
                "    GetObjectPresignedUrl <bucketName> <keyName> \n\n" +
                "Where:\n" +
                "    bucketName - the Amazon S3 bucket name. \n\n"+
                "    keyName - a key name that represents a text file. \n\n";

        if (args.length != 2) {
           System.out.println(USAGE);
           System.exit(1);
        }

        String bucketName = args[0];
        String keyName = args[1];
        Region region = Region.US_WEST_2;
        S3Presigner presigner = S3Presigner.builder()
                .region(region)
                .build();

        getPresignedUrl(presigner, bucketName, keyName);
        presigner.close();

    }
      // snippet-start:[presigned.java2.getobjectpresigned.main]
       public static void getPresignedUrl(S3Presigner presigner, String bucketName, String keyName ) {

        try {
            GetObjectRequest getObjectRequest =
                    GetObjectRequest.builder()
                            .bucket(bucketName)
                            .key(keyName)
                            .build();

            GetObjectPresignRequest getObjectPresignRequest =  GetObjectPresignRequest.builder()
                            .signatureDuration(Duration.ofMinutes(10))
                            .getObjectRequest(getObjectRequest)
                             .build();

            // Generate the presigned request
            PresignedGetObjectRequest presignedGetObjectRequest =
                    presigner.presignGetObject(getObjectPresignRequest);

            // Log the presigned URL
            System.out.println("Presigned URL: " + presignedGetObjectRequest.url());

            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) presignedGetObjectRequest.url().openConnection();
            presignedGetObjectRequest.httpRequest().headers().forEach((header, values) -> {
                values.forEach(value -> {
                    connection.addRequestProperty(header, value);
                });
            });

            // Send any request payload that the service needs (not needed when isBrowserExecutable is true)
            if (presignedGetObjectRequest.signedPayload().isPresent()) {
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                try (InputStream signedPayload = presignedGetObjectRequest.signedPayload().get().asInputStream();
                     OutputStream httpOutputStream = connection.getOutputStream()) {
                    IoUtils.copy(signedPayload, httpOutputStream);
                }
            }

            // Download the result of executing the request
            try (InputStream content = connection.getInputStream()) {
                System.out.println("Service returned response: ");
                IoUtils.copy(content, System.out);
            }

        } catch (S3Exception e) {
            e.getStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.getStackTrace();
        }
    }
    // snippet-end:[presigned.java2.getobjectpresigned.main]
}
```

**UPDATE**

The above Java code will produce a pre-signed URL. Debug through it and get the pre-signed URL at line 86.

I also tested the above code with a file name **people.png**. In the Github repo, there is a [Java Swing example](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/javav2/example_code/s3/src/main/java/com/example/s3/PresignedSwing.java) that you can enter the pre-signed URL and the file is downloaded. Modify lines 50 and 53 in the Java Swing app.

[image]

This app downloaded the people PNG file to a local file where it can be opened.

[image]